# Sum same Range across multiple sheets (sheets are named range)

Tags: dynamic, excel-formula, named-ranges

I have a named range where it dynamically select from the 1st available cell to the last available non-blank cell. And this cell contains the sheet name.

So my question is:

How do I go about summing this cell from the same cell using the named range sheet name?

For example, without the named range, I could do

```
=SUM('Sheet1:Sheet100'!A1)
```

How can I use the named range i.e. Sheet1To100 in this case, to sum the sheet in the same cell.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Was able to find it by trial and error, although I don't really know as to the reason why it works.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUM(INDIRECT("'"&Sheet1To100&"'!A1")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Below formula should also work for you:

```
 =SUM(N(INDIRECT(Sheet1To100 & "!A1")))
```

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

`N` function converts value to a number. For details see [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/N-function-a624cad1-3635-4208-b54a-29733d1278c9).